# Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': The specified module could not be found

Tags: c#, dll, sqlite

I'm having a heck of a time getting my tests to run against my SQLite Data Provider.

I've looked at the suggested links [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Unable%20to%20load%20DLL%20%27sqlite3%27:), but none of them seem to get me going down the right path.

I've downloaded the Windows [Precompiled Binaries for sqlite3.dll](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html)

I've copied the sqlite3.dll into both my `Sqlite\bin` directory as well as my `Tests\bin` directory
[image: dll copied into bin directories]

Unfortunately when I run my tests, I get the following error

[image: failed test]

Is there a clear cut way to get this working both in my Windows dev environment (primary goal right now) as well as running in Android and IOS (required in the near future)?

Also, if it matters, here are my Sqlite project references.

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that the assembly needs to reside in the output directory, not the `bin` directory.

Comment: You are using 'Copy Local'(dll properties) true?

Comment: moving the dll into the bin\debug directory yields a new error `System.BadImageFormatException : An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)` Looks like it has to do with x86/x64

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4744293/62576 didn't help?

Comment: It would appear as though I need to use the `Sqlite.Interop.dll` files, and rename it to `sqlite3.dll`. Now the only problem I'm going to run into is if the build is run on a different platform x8x / x64

Comment: Instead of doing this manually, did you try installing SQLite with NuGet? It will add the references and put everything in place, and have both x86 and x64 versions installed.

Comment: yes I did, however the file names are incorrect. The tests were originally showing the need for `sqlite3` and nuget pulls down `SQLite.Interop` which you can see in my screenshot above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the answer for me was quite simple. I wired up a Pre-Build event that checks the architecture of the machine, and copies the appropriate dll into the output bin directory.

Now anyone on our team can simply run `REBUILD`, and the proper dll will be available to run against SQLite.

```text
if '$(PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE)'=='AMD64' (xcopy /y "$(ProjectDir)x64\sqlite3.dll" ".\") 
if '$(PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE)'=='x86' (xcopy /y "$(ProjectDir)x86\sqlite3.dll" ".\")
if '$(PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432)'=='AMD64' (xcopy /y "$(ProjectDir)x64\sqlite3.dll" ".\")
```

Answer (score 3):

When I add the following libraries the error went away

1. Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package (V11.0)
2. SQLite for Windows Runtime (V3.8.7.1)

[image: When I add the following libraries the error went away]

Answer (score 0):

Can't put this in comments, so here's what I got: [image]

Also, have a look at [Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028069/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite-interop-dll).

Last, but not least, did you try to add a reference to the SQLite.Inetrop.dll (in the references)? 
References -> add -> just browse to where your SQLite is, select view all, and add a reference to the Interop.dll as well)

Comment: my project can't use the dll's directly from nuget. We're using a different version of Mono.Data.Sqlite, and the sqlite3.dll cannot be referenced in the project as it is not a .net dll.

Comment: You cannot add SQLite.Interop.dll with references->add. This is because SQLite.Interop.dll is unmanaged and therefore not valid.

Answer (score 0):

I am using VS2017 and solved the issue by adding the following task to copy the assembly.

```
<Target Name="Ensure SQLite assemblies copied" AfterTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x64' ">
  <Copy SourceFiles="$(OutDir)x64\SQLite.Interop.dll" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)" />
</Target>
```