# SQLite UWP Error with Mobile EMulator Windows 10

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I am getting the following error when I run the Mobile Emulator while trying to compile and run a VS 2015 UWP app. The app runs fine when using the Local Machine or Simulator.

```
   System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233036
  Message=The type initializer for 'SQLitePCL.raw' threw an exception.
  Source=SQLitePCL.raw
  TypeName=SQLitePCL.raw
  StackTrace:
       at SQLitePCL.raw.sqlite3_open_v2(String filename, sqlite3& db, Int32 flags, String vfs)
       at SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String databasePath, SQLiteOpenFlags openFlags, Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks)
       at SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String databasePath, Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks)
       at App3.MainPage.LoadSQLData()
       at App3.MainPage..ctor()
       at App3.App3_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_0_MainPage()
       at App3.App3_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance()
  InnerException: 
       HResult=-2146233052
       Message=Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
       Source=SQLitePCL.raw
       TypeName=""
       StackTrace:
            at SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider.NativeMethods.sqlite3_win32_set_directory(UInt32 directoryType, String directoryPath)
            at SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider..ctor()
            at SQLitePCL.raw..cctor()
```

I have the following references:
SQLite for Universal Windows 3.9.1
sqlite-net-pcl
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Runtime Package for Universal Windows

The code where the error occurs in the "using (var db......:

```
 int recCtr = 0;
        var root = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
        var dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "BaseBallOU.db");
        List<string> NHLCollection = new List<string>();
        using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
        {
            var NHLlist = db.Table<Teams>().ToList();
            foreach (var item in NHLlist)
            {
                recCtr++;
                NHLCollection.Add(item.TeamName.ToString());
            }
        }
```

I see a number of similar posts, but some are dated and not using the most recent SQLite libs and pcls.

I'm looking for the correct SQLite dlls, sqlite pcls, runtimes (e.g. VC++ 2013? And version numbers that can be used to compile and run a UWP app on both the local machine and phone emulator.

TIA

Comment: Did you try using the correct WinRT platform setup? `using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), dbPath))`    My sample still works (tried on local machine and emulator) http://igrali.com/2015/05/01/using-sqlite-in-windows-10-universal-apps/

Answer (score 8):

Following is how I work with SQLite:

1. Download and install Sqlite visual studio extension from http://sqlite.org/download.html
   [image]
2. Create a new blank c# Universal Windows Platform app.
3. Right click on the References of project -> Add Reference -> Universal Windows -> Extension -> add SQLite for Universal App Platform and its dependency Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal Windows
   [image]
4. Right click on the project node -> Manage NuGet packages -> Search SQLite.Net-PCL -> Install the default version 3.0.5
   [image]
5. Change your code to the following:

   ```
   using (var db = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), dbPath))
   {
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: Alan, I followed your example step-by-step and got the following error message for both the Local Machine and Emulator X86/Debug trials.                            System.DllNotFoundException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233052
  Message=Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
  Source=SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT
  TypeName=""
 EmulatorTest1.EmulatorTest1_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance()
  InnerException:

Comment: I have exactly the same trouble by follwoing same steps, any idea?

Comment: does the issue occur in a clean blank project? if so, check your VS updates to ensure you are not running into any known issue of the tools.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1: Install SQLite VSIX pacakge for Universal Windows Platform development using Visual Studio 2015**

https://www.sqlite.org/2016/sqlite-uwp-3130000.vsix

**Step 2: Install NuGet package SQLite.NET-PCL**

PM> Install-Package SQLite.NET-PCL

**Step 3: Add references**

Add Reference -> Universal Windows ->Extensions -> Make sure the following packages have been checked:
"SQLite for Universal Windows Platform"
"Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal Windows Platform Apps"

If you didn't add reference for VC++ 2015 Runtime, you will get an error mentioned that "Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3' in SQLite Net Platform WinRT" when creating DB connection.

Comment: I have also tried another NuGet Package "sqlite-net-pcl", it seems not require other packages.