# How to install SQLite for .NET 4.X in Unity

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, unity-game-engine, android-sqlite

My project was working for .NET 2.X in unity and recently upgraded to .NET 4.X and since then my SQLite has not been working as I receive the error message on the android device:

`DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': The specified module could not be found.`

However, I do not believe this is the full issue because I do not receive this issue on iOS only on android.

I was wondering if someone could assist in the process of installing SQLite for android.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744293/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite3-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-exceptio/26715609

Comment: I have SQLite for x64 and x86 already, and that doesn't seem to be too applicable to Unity and especially for android